# IMapTrigger for Azure web jobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I want to run a web job if a specific email is received. Currently, I use a TimerTrigger and create an ImapClient which reads the unread emails and scans for one with the appropriate content. This works fine but there is a delay of whatever duration I set my timer to. Ideally, I would like an IMapTrigger (if such a thing exists) which would fire whenever a new email appears.

Does a) such a thing exist, b) is it worth writing one?

Comment: dont know if it already exists but you can write your own: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings. Where do your emails come from ? you can use a logic app if we re talking about a o365 account.

Comment: Check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow works with o365 outlook and gmail

Comment: @Thomas I can send the emails to any address I want, basically, they are sent by Azure. I might be able to rethink the whole thing I want to do as a  logic app, thanks.

Comment: Yeah logic app will be helpful as you can use existing trigger/connector. Logic app pricing is pretty cheap so depends on the volume